# How could Android call Google Play Store in-app like iOS?

Tags: android, ios

We have developed an app for years and we have a lot of users for that app.

These days, we developed a new App and we want to drive some users to the new App from the old App.

We want users to install the new App without jumping out from our old app. So we decide to call the App Store Page in a modal style.

It's quite easy for iOS, just use `SKStoreProductViewController` and `loadProductWithParameters`.

It looks like:

[image]

Then we tried to do the same in Android, we found the ads on Youtube is achieved by a modal Google Play Store:

[image]

Unfortunately, we found no Class in Android SDK could achieve that like `SKStoreProductViewController` in iOS.

So, my question is, how could I achieve a modal app store which supports in-app install in Android? Is there any class in Android SDK or other Package so we can reuse instead of developing that feature from scratch?

Comment: Great question. Any solution found ? Thanks!